# How to install a SharePoint Add-In in Office 365 Germany

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, add-ins

We created Office 365 Germany subscription and tried to install SharePoint Add-ins from SharePoint store. We were able to in install none of the available add-ins from the store. All of them throw this error:

> "Everything is fine, but we had a small problem getting your license.
>   Please go back to the SharePoint store to get this app again and you
>   won't be charged for it."

[image]

Our partners submitted a ticket to Microsoft and they replied that software providers have to update Add-Ins for German Cloud. We tried to find any options related to German Cloud in our Microsoft Seller Dashboard, with no luck.

I'm not able to find any guidance on this on the Internet as well.

All the add-ins from the store throw the same error. This doesn't look like a problem of a software provider.

So, what are requirements to make SharePoint add-in work in German Cloud (Office 365 German)?

Comment: The system account is the problem. Try adding the app with a different account which is not a system account. Also, that particular account should be a SCA or must have Full Control on the site

Comment: Just created a regular user and granted Full Control on current site only. The error is the same.